# Create a counting variable

Tags: r, sequence, counting

I am given a vector "a":

```
a <-c(2, 1, 5)
```

From this I need to create a vector (i.e. counting variable) that looks like that:

```
b <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

My input will be "a" the output should be "b".

So I want to count until I reach the first element in a(1)=2 --> 1,2; then I count until I reach the second element a(2)=1 --> 1; then the third a(3) --> 1,2,3,4,5;
Then combine it in one vector to get b=1,**2**,**1**,1,2,3,4,**5**

Comment: You can do `b <- sequence(a)`

Comment: c(2,1,5) --> 1, **2**, **1**, 1, 2, 3, 4, **5** --> so you always start counting at 1 and count until you reach each element in vector a

Answer (score 2):

Hello I don't know if it's the best answer but it works

```
b <- unlist(sapply(a,function(x) 1:x))
```

edit : Jogo answer `sequence(a)` should be used